getopts used to parse function parameters failing to do so
I have been hours trying to troubleshoot this but I give, up.
I will try to specify the question as much generically as I can
I have a script script.sh which has a main function. In it it executes one other function parse_csv . This parse_csv function I have make it accept parameters, parse them with getopts then those Variables parsed are been typed checked.
I have found this as a neat way of working on bash sort of like a type check, so I have made all the helper functions of this script work this way.
Anyways the issue is been caused in this part of the code.
script.sh

while getopts "r:f:n:l:w:h" opt; do
    case $opt in
        r)  # Return host
            RETURN_CONNECTION_STRING=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        f)  # URL list file
            url_list=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        n)  # Project name
            PROJECT_NAME=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        l)  # Byte limit
            BYTE_LIMIT=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        w)  # Server username@IP:port
            server_args+="-S ${OPTARG} "
            ((no_hosts++))
            ;;
        h)  # Show help
            show_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)  # Invalid option
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            show_help
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done


main() {
    ## If process has been altered changes_file will exist, merge it first
    if [[ -e ${changes_file} ]]; then
        echo "An unmerged ${changes_file} was found !!" >&2 
        echo "Probably from an unfinnished process" >&2
        echo update_csv -o ${url_list} -c ${changes_file}
        update_csv -o "${url_list}" -c "${changes_file}"
        rm "${changes_file}"
        echo rm "${changes_file}"
    fi

}

main


update_csv(){
    ## Given an original_file .csv with two columns
    ##    And a changes_file
    ##              - Same first column fields
    ##              - Different second columnd fields
    ##              - Rows may be disordered
    ##  Update the original file keeping the order of rows
    ##      It will update by creating a buffer_file
    ##         This is made in mind for large files modification
    ##            Should the process get interrupted 
    ##                buffer_file will be there

    ## PARSING ARGUMENTS ---------------------------------
    ## ---------------------------------------------------
    # Initialize variables
    original_file=""
    changes_file=""
    echo ${1} ${2} ${3} ${4}

    # Parse options using getopts
    while getopts "o:c:" opt; do
        case "${opt}" in
            o) original_file="${OPTARG}" ;;
            c) changes_file="${OPTARG}" ;;
            *) 
                echo "Usage: update_csv -o original_file.csv -c changes_file.csv" >&2
                return 1
                ;;
        esac
    done


    # Check if both original_file and changes_file are provided
    if [[ -z "${original_file}" || -z "${changes_file}" ]]; then
        echo "Usage: update_csv -o original_file.csv -c changes_file.csv" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}


When running script with
./script.sh -f /home/fakuve/downloads/vim-dan/shopify2/https___shopify.dev.csv
It gives me the error check of
Usage: update_csv -o original_file.csv -c changes_file.csv

It is quite rare cause the command afterwards rm is failing its execution too
rm: missing operand

But the echo the line echo update_csv -o ${url_list} -c ${changes_file}
Gives me the correct expansion
update_csv -o /home/fakuve/downloads/vim-dan/shopify2/https___shopify.dev.csv -c /home/fakuve/downloads/vim-dan/shopify2/https___shopify.dev_ch.csv

Looks like the bug takes place in the function update_csv() , as If I place the line of  rm "${changes_file}" before that function call , it will operate correctly.

You didn't reset (or localize) OPTIND. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336595/in-bash-why-does-using-getopts-in-a-function-only-work-once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439994/getopts-in-sourced-bash-function-works-interactively-but-not-in-test-script and cross https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233728/bash-function-with-getopts-only-works-the-first-time-its-run https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525048/getopts-in-function-that-is-called-more-than-once-in-a-script-getopts-doesnt-d
